# Unable to rotate in a right axis inside the image in Qml

Tags: qt, rotation, qml, speedometer

I'm trying to rotate my image needle for the respective speed values  in a speedometer, but I'm not sure which are the right values for origin.x and origin.y, I have tried a lot of times with trial and error but couldn't able to achieve the output. Kindly help me if anyone knows it.

expected: needle should rotate in a circumference of circle indicating speed values.

I have tried this:

```
import QtQuick

import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: root

    width: 637
    height: 750
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        id: img

        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "Speedometer.png"

        Image {
            id: needle

            property double needleAngle : 0

            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 40
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 100
            antialiasing: true

            source: "dial_with_meter.png"
            rotation: 240

            transform: Rotation { origin.x: needle.width/2; origin.y: needle.height/2
                angle: -36 + needle.needleAngle }
            Behavior on rotation {
                SmoothedAnimation {
                    velocity: 50
                }
            }

        }
    }

    Button {
        id: btn1

        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 100
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 50
        text: "Btn1"

        onClicked: {
            needle.needleAngle += 1
        }

    }

    Button {
        id: btn2

        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 250
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 50
        text: "Btn2"

    }
}
```

[image]

And I'm trying to achieve needle rotation for this UI

[image]

After your suggestions Jurgen,
needle is rotating backwards, but i want that should be shown towards the speed values, as i mentioned in the image above, here is the output of your suggestion i used:

[image]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put the needle onto a `Item` and center and rotate the `Item`. The needle is put at the top center. So it is rotating correctly with the rotated item.

A short example based on your code:

```
Image {
    id: img

    anchors.centerIn: parent
    source: "qrc://qt/images/background.png"

    Item {
        id: rectangle

        width: 300
        height: 300

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        property double needleAngle : 0

        transform: Rotation {
            origin.x: rectangle.width / 2;
            origin.y: rectangle.height / 2
            angle: rectangle.needleAngle
        }

        Timer {
            running: true
            interval: 100
            repeat: true

            onTriggered: {
                rectangle.needleAngle += 10
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: needle
            x: (rectangle.width - needle.width) / 2
            source: "qrc://qt/images/arrow.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Better approaches will be based on a `Dial` item, I guess.

Comment: Currently after using your suggestion, needle is rotating backwards, but expected should be needle should show towards the speed values, how can be achieved, can you suggest please.

Comment: Flip your needle Image.

Comment: do we have any property for that @JurgenLutz ?
I tried using mirror property, but now the needle is upward, expected should be always needle face to speed values.

Comment: use your favorit graphics programm and create a needle image pointing straight up.

Comment: This is more or less the solution I would go for to. As an interesting note, the `Item` only needs to be anchored (which you've already done), it doesn't need dimension, so, we could safely remove `width: 300` and `height: 300` and it will still work. The devil is in the detail such as rotation range and configuring the needle Image. Which (a) yes, edit the image in a 3rd party application, (b) put an additional `rotation: <insert_your_angle>` property on the needle Image.

Comment: I just used Paint application to flip my image to 90 degree, now it is working fine with angle, Thank you so much Stephen and Jurgen. :)

Comment: Great! Think about accepting the answere if it solved your problem.